# Problem in displaying a GeoTiff image in JMapFrame

Tags: coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, geotools

I'm trying to display a GeoTiff image with no projection but where the geographical extent (bounding box) is known:

```java
reader= format.getReader(new File(sImageName));
GridCoverage2D gridCoverage= reader.getGridCoverage2D(null);
ReferencedEnvelope referencedEnvelope= new ReferencedEnvelope(-106,
-105,55,56, CRS.decode('EPSG:4326', true));
MapContext map= new DefaultMapContext();
map.setCoordinateReferenceSystem(CRS.decode('EPSG:4326', true));
map.setAreaOfInterest(referencedEnvelope, CRS.decode('EPSG:4326', true));
map.addLayer(reader, rasterStyle);
JMapPane pane= new JMapPane();
pane.setMapContext(map);
```

It does not work (with GeoTools 2.7.5), I get

java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.geotools.swing.JMapPane.setTransforms(JMapPane.java:1114)
        at org.geotools.swing.JMapPane.doSetDisplayArea(JMapPane.java:607)
        at org.geotools.swing.JMapPane.doSetMapContext(JMapPane.java:505)
        at org.geotools.swing.JMapPane.setMapContext(JMapPane.java:472)

It used to work in an earlier version of GeoTools (2.7.2) with a simpler version of the code:

```
reader= format.getReader(new File(sImageName));
GridCoverage2D gridCoverage= reader.getGridCoverage2D(null);
MapContext map= new DefaultMapContext();
map.addLayer(reader, rasterStyle);
JMapPane pane= new JMapPane();
pane.setMapContext(map);
map.setCoordinateReferenceSystem(CRS.decode('EPSG:4326', true));
```

Comment: I'd break CRS.decode(...) out to a variable and check it isn't null before using it. Root problem is probably a missing epsg jar.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem seems that the library gt-swing-2.7.5.jar is unsupported and therefore does not work properly anymore. The best is to take the corresponding code in GeoTools 8.0 which seems to be the development branch and adapt it for GeoTools 2.7.5.

Comment: The best bet is probably to upgrade to the latest stable release rather than back porting bits and peices.